# how every simple and noabelian group will be not nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

this question arise when I was searching about tarski monsters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group.this group is nilpotent because it is simple and noabelian,now I don't know how it is true.

it will be great if you help me.thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Looking at the upper central series, it is obvious that one necessary condition for a group to be nilpotent is to have non-trivial center...